# perforce shorter client directory structure

Tags: windows, perforce, long-integer, pathname

This is a very basic query, but I am using perforce to create a workspace for a particular project that is deep in the depot directory.
Hence, on windows I am facing a warning as to "File name ... exceeds the limit of 260 characters"
I am trying to search a way to limit the folder structure to something just like : "C:\p4\dept.. " without the long list of folders.
Is there an easy way to do this?
I have come across following similar solution on :
[http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3051?startURL=%2Farticles%2FKB_Article%2FSubmitting-or-Syncing-Files-with-Long-Path-Names][1]

But, cannot find out the command execution.
Is there a better, easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

The local paths (which exceed 260 chars in your case) are composed by concatenating

1. the workspace root
2. the paths (relative to the workspace root) as defined by your mapping.

To shorten the two, open Connection > Edit Current Workspace in P4V. Then

1. Shorten your *Workspace root* (e.g. to `C:\p4`)
2. Shorten your mappings:

   1. In the same dialog as above, expand *Workspace Mappings*. This may be displayed as a graphical tree view. If that's the case, click one of the icons near its top-right corner to switch to a text-area view.
   2. In the text-area view, each line has two parts: the depot path and the local path. The local path is something like `//foo/some/relative/path/to/bar`, where `foo` is your *Workspace name*. Shorten it to something like `//foo/bar`.

This should produce much shorter local paths.

Comment: Thank you @sferencik !! This was very helpful.